# Can not read property of toArrays of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read CSV file data, but I got an error. Any solution appreciated. after adding libaray it still not working

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// The event listener for the file upload
document.getElementById('File').addEventListener('change', upload, false);

// Method that checks that the browser supports the HTML5 File API
function browserSupportFileUpload() {
    var isCompatible = false;
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    isCompatible = true;
    }
    return isCompatible;
}

// Method that reads and processes the selected file
function upload(evt) {
if (!browserSupportFileUpload()) {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser!');
    } else {
        var data = null;
        var file = evt.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var csvData = event.target.result;
            data = $.csv.toArrays(csvData);
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
              // alert('Imported -' + data.length + '- rows successfully!');
              $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                $i = 0;
                // console.log(value[$i]);
                $('p').
              })
            } else {
                alert('No data to import!');
            }
        };
        reader.onerror = function() {
            alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
        };
    }
}
});
```

Comment: `$.csv` is undefined. Is it a library you've not included in the page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you suggest the link of the library

Comment: Not really. There's not enough info, as Google shows multiple unrelated results. Surely you know which library is being used?

Comment: This maybe? https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv

Comment: Maybe this helps https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-csv

Comment: `.toArray()` does not accept parameters remove `csvData` and remove the s at the end of name it's not `.toArray` **s** `()`

Comment: @zer00ne 1. That depends on the library 2. The OP is using `toArrays()`, not `toArray()`

Comment: @RobinSingh I'd suggest deleting this question then as it was a configuration problem and isn't likely to help any future visitors